# Read CSV for same headers and separate in dict

Tags: python

So I am getting a CSV in API request, the format of CSV is-

`"id","loc_name","qty","loc_name","qty"
    "NM001","HLR","10","KBD","20"
    "NM003","KMG","15","SLD","25"`

and I want a dict in this format: 
`{"NM001":{'HLR':'10', 'KBD':'20'}, "NM003":{"KMG": "15", "SLD": "25"}}`

tried code-

`field_names = next(csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=","))
 csv_file_handler = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=",",fieldnames=field_names)
for each_row in islice(csv_file_handler, 1, None):
    print each_row`

- here csv_file is the file i am getting in the response.

result = `{'id': 'NM001', 'loc_name': 'KBD', 'qty': '20'}
        {'id': 'NM003', 'loc_name': 'SLD', 'qty': '25'}`

the problem in csv.DictReader is that it will return only the last value because the headers are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `pandas` module for handling `csv` files. I would tackle this problem probably this way (although not the best way possible I assume and not the best way in pandas. But hey, it works.

```
import pandas as pd
# read the csv as DataFrame, probably there is a way to get it from
# the API directly without saving to a file
# specify header as the first row
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=0)
# empty dict
d = {}
# iterate over lines, I use this way, but I don't like it in fact
for i, key_id in enumerate(df["id"]):
    # assign the values the way you want it
    # however you need to specify it by names
    # or indices
    d[key_id.strip()] = {df.loc[i, "loc_name"]:df.loc[i, "qty"],
                         df.loc[i, "loc_name.1"]:df.loc[i, "qty.1"]}
print(d)
#{'"NM003"': {'SLD': 25, 'KMG': 15}, '"NM001"': {'HLR': 10, 'KBD': 20}}
```

If you want this to work with additional columns (which must come in pair: `key:val`), then you can use `df.ix[<row>,<col>]` and iterate first over rows (as before) and then over columns (add if to add only non `nan` values):

```
for i, key_id in enumerate(df["id"]):
    # create empty dict
    d[key_id.strip()] = {}
    # a less python more C-like syntax
    # go through cols, skip the first and step is 2
    for j in range(1, len(df.columns), 2):
        # if there is some entry
        if not pd.isnull(df.ix[i,j]):
            d[key_id.strip()][df.ix[i, j]] = df.ix[i, j+1]
```

Comment: looks good, but what if the size of csv changes. As you are doing it by hard codind `{df.loc[i, "loc_name"]:df.loc[i, "qty"],
                      df.loc[i, "loc_name.1"]:df.loc[i, "qty.1"]}`
can we ignore this ?

Comment: That depends, what `the size of csv changes` means. Do you refer to rows or columns? You can use `df.ix[<row>, <col>]` and use int indices and swap that code for this: `{df.ix[i, 1]:df.ix[i, 2], df.ix[i, 3]:df.ix[i, 4]}`.

Comment: there can be N number of rows or columns. So have to iterate this.

Comment: And it holds, that first column is dict key and then it is in pairs (second, third columns) are (key, val) and (fourth, fifth columns) are (key, val)?

Comment: yes the format will always remain same. It's like the  first row of csv is header and the 1st column is the dict key, and then all are the others are  key,val pair to that key. Also the no of rows and column are not fixed. 
ex:
`"id","loc_name","qty"
"NM001","HLR","10","KBD","20"
"NM003","KMG","15","KBD","25"
"NM004","HLR","20","KMG","30","KBD","25","MNT","90","CSG","5"`

Comment: See my updated answer, I am not sure, how it behaves on rows with different number of columns, probably fails.

Comment: It looks like `pandas` fails to load `csv` file, where `no. columns < no.rows`. I've added enough columns names, then it works, however rows without enough entries ended up with `{nan:nan}` in the dict.

Comment: its working!! but a small issue is there are  some NAN values in the dict.

d= `{'NM001': {nan: nan, 'HLR': 10, 'KBD': 20}, 'NM003': {'KMG': 15, nan: nan, 'KBD': 25}, 'NM004': {'KMG': 30, 'CSG': 5.0, 'MNT': 90.0, 'HLR': 20, 'KBD': 25.0}}`

Comment: As I wrote before, those `nan:nan` correspond to the missing entries when you call `df.ix[i,j]` but  `df.ix[i,j]` is not there. I've added an `if` statement, to check for missing values.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it like this:

```
result = dict()
for line in file:
    line = line.split('","')
    id = line[0][1:]
    l_n_1 = line[1]
    qty_1 = line[2]
    l_n_2 = line[3]
    qty_2 = line[4][:-1]

    if(id != "id"):
        result[id] = {l_n_1: qty_1, l_n_2: qty_2}

print(result)
```

This works and handles it like you want to.

I opened a local file, but it should be possible from an API request as well. My file looked like this:

```
"id","loc_name","qty","loc_name","qty"
"NM001","HLR","10","KBD","20"
"NM003","KMG","15","SLD","25"
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
results = [{'id': 'NM001', 'loc_name': 'KBD', 'qty': '20'}, {'id': 'NM003', 'loc_name': 'SLD', 'qty': '25'}]
```

You can get what you want by:-

```
result_dicts = { res['id']: res for res in results }
for _, result_dict in result_dicts.items():
    result_dict.pop('id')
```